# changing destination JSP page and servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm new to JSP and Servlet so please bear with me for a while!
I have a problem regarding the communication between JSP and Servlet.

I am trying to create a LogIn Page.

This is my Index JSP page for LogIN

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
    <head><title>  index.jsp</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="orange">
    <h2> <font color=white> JSP index.jsp at</font>
            <%= request.getContextPath () %>
            <font color=white>
            </font></h2><hr>


            <form action="LibrarySysServlet" method ="POST">
            <font color=navy><h3>Login</h3>
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> MemberId </td>
                    <td align="left"><input type="text" name="memId" length="30"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Password </td>
                    <td align="left"><input type="text" name="password" length="30"/></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <br>
                <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>

                </font>
            </form>

            <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am really confused on what to put for the form action for the index page when logging in as the destination changes according to whether the logIn is correct or not.

For my Servlet side, i tried to scan in index page and pass it through a function to check whether logIn is correct and redirect it according to the different answer.

However when run, it does not redirect but it just proceeds to whatever was specified in form action.

Short snippet of the code (didn't paste the whole thing because it was too long):

```
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher;
                ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext(); //links to index.JSP

                String page = request.getPathInfo();
                page = page.substring(1);


                if ("index".equals(page)) {
                    if (logIn(request)) {
                      dispatcher= servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp");
                     } else {
                     dispatcher= servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/Menu.jsp");
                     }
                 }
```

HELP really confused ! WHat am i doing wrong??

Comment: index.jsp is the first asp that is being run.

Comment: do a `redirect` instead of `forward`, else `LibrarySysServlet` will persist in the url.

Answer (score 0):

```
  RequestDispatcher dispatcher;
                ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext(); //links to index.JSP

               //check here your username and password and put into a variable true or false



                    if (variable== true) {
                      dispatcher= servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp");
                     } else {
                     dispatcher= servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/Menu.jsp");
                     }
             }
```

Comment: I did that though by passing it through another function. However i think my index page is not communicating with my servlet.

Comment: You mean `if (variable)`, and probably meant to just change the JSP instead of duplicating the dispatcher code.

Answer (score 0):

it is better off to use reponse.sendRedirect("{url}") not dispatcher.

Also test your logIn method see if it works as you wish

Comment: and also i think request.getPathInfo() should not be "index".... try a System.out.println(page) to debug

Comment: Hi i tried it but i realized that it is creating exception cases in my servlet meaning not its not even running through try{} but rather it is caught as an exception. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the container and use FORM-based authentication.  In the web.xml:

```
   <login-config>
      <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
      <form-login-config>
         <form-login-page>login.html</form-login-page>
         <form-error-page>login_error.html</form-error-page>
      </form-login-config>
   </login-config>
```

then in the login.html:

```
   Please log in:
   <form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
      <input type="text" name="j_username">
      <input type="password" name="j_password">
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
   </form>
```

You must use j_security_check, j_username, and j_password for this to work.